# jExcel getting cell content missing

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I read excel file correctly.For example my cell content is 0,987654321 in excel file.When I  read it with jExcel api i reads just few chars of cell.For example 0,987.

here is my read excel code part:

```
 Cell A = sheet.getCell(1, 1);
 String stringA = A.getContents().toString();
```

How can I fix that problem.I want all content of cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getContents()` is a basic routine to get the cell's content as a string.  By casting the cell to the appropriate type (after testing that it's the expected type) you get access to the raw numeric value contained, like this

```
if (A.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
    NumberCell nc = (NumberCell) A;
    double doubleA = nc.getValue();
    // this is a double containing the exact numeric value that was stored 
    // in the spreadsheet
}
```

The key message here is: you can access any type of cell by casting to the appropriate subtype of Cell.
All this and a lot more is explained in the [jexcelapi tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

And in short:

```
if (A.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
    double doubleA = ((NumberCell) sheet.getCell(1, 1)).getValue();
}
```